# Shell in c using strtok and an array of pointers

Tags: c, shell

For this Shell program i'm using the functions strtok (see fragmenta.h code) to parsing a string which is introduced by user.
I need to remove the blanks with strotk function and introduce those on a struct of an array of pointers. This are made in fragmenta.h

In the main program (shell.c), is necessary to introduce the string, this one is passed to fragmenta and stored on char **arg. After that, i use the execvp function to execute the command.

The problem is that the program store the whole command, but only execute the first individual command. For example, if we introduce "ls -al", only execute the ls command so i understand that is a problem on the pointer.

Main program shell.c

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "fragmenta.h"
//
char cadena[50];
int pid;
int i, status;
char **arg;
pid_t pid;
//
main()
{
    printf("minishell  -> ");
    printf("Introduce the command \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", cadena);
    if (strcmp(cadena, "exit") == 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            printf("Error in fork()\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) //child proccess
        {
            arg = fragmenta(cadena);
            if (execvp(*arg, arg) < 0)      /* execute the command  */
            {
                printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else                                   /* for the parent:      */
        {
            while (wait(&status) != pid);
        }
    }
}

int len;
char *dest;
char *ptr;
char *aux;
char **fragmenta(const char *cadena)
{
    //
    char *token;
    int i = 0;
    //
    len = strlen(cadena);
    char *cadstr[len + 1];
    dest = (char *)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(dest, cadena);
    //printf("Has introducido:%s\n",dest);
    token = strtok(dest, " ");
    while ( token != NULL)
    {
        cadstr[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(cadstr[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    *cadstr[i] = '\0';
    ptr = *cadstr;
    i = 0;
    while (cadstr[i] != NULL)
    {
        //printf("almacenado: %s\n",cadstr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return &ptr;
}
```

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. `scanf` is a PITA to use.

Comment: can you show fragmenta pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got at least two problems.

The first one is this:

```
ptr=*cadstr;
```

You've gone through all that trouble to create an array of arguments, and then you just copy the first argument and return a pointer to that copy.

You could just get rid of `ptr` and `return cadstr`, except that it's a local variable, so as soon as the function returns, it can be overwritten or deallocated.

Since you're storing everything else in the universe as globals for some reason, the obvious fix to that is to make `cadstr` global too. (Of course you can't use a C99 runtime-length array that way, but since you've written your code to guarantee a buffer overrun if the input is more than 50 characters, you can safely just allocate it to 50 strings.)

A better solution would be to initialize a new array on the heap and copy all of `cadstr` into it. Or just initialize `cadstr` on the heap in the first place.

---

Second, you never append a `NULL` to the end of `cadstr`. Instead, you do this:

```
*cadstr[i] = '\0';
```

That leaves the last element in `cadstr` pointing to whatever uninitialized pointer it was pointing to, but modifies the first byte of whatever that is to be a `0`. That could corrupt important memory, or cause a segfault, or be totally harmless, but the one thing it can't do is set `cadstr[i]` to point to NULL.

When you check this:

```
i = 0;
while (cadstr[i] != NULL)
   i++;
```

… you only get out of that loop because of luck; you read right past the end of the allocated array and keep going until some other structure or some uninitialized memory happens to be `sizeof(void*)` 0s in a row.

And when you pass the same thing to `execvp`, who knows what it's going to do.

---

You're also declaring `main` without a prototype, which is deprecated, so you'll probably get a warning for it from any compiler that accepted the rest of your code. To fix that, just do `int main()`.